# How can I bulk archive forms submitted with a shared login on CommCare?

Tags: commcare

Is there a way to leverage the bulk archive function in CommCare to archive forms submitted under a shared username?

We have the capability of identifying the `case_ids` from a registration form that contains data identifying the specific users, and subsequently want to archive all the follow-up forms associated with that case (that are presumably submitted by the same person).

Comment: Is there any chance that the forms you need archived all happened during a certain time period?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how to filter the Manage Forms report is by user, date, and form. It seems in this case you cannot depend on a unique form, or a unique user. I don't think the Manage Forms report is going to give you the precision to identify the forms you want based on the data you have.

Unfortunately CommCare doesn't support or encourage users to share the same username.